# Python: Random forest code optimization

Tags: python, performance, random

I've been working on random forest algorithm for classification with roulette selection to find best splits. I came up with this homebrew based on this article https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-random-forest-scratch-python/. It works well enough, but I have a major problem with execution time. It's reasonably fast for 1-6 trees, but it completely chokes on 7 and more. I'm looking for ways to make it more efficient, so it doesn't take a month to finish basic tests. I'm a beginner and I don't know much about optimizing code, so I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I could improve. Here's the link to Github repo: https://github.com/pdabrow11/Random-Forest-Roulette. It contains all .py files and datasets used for classification. Here's the raw code:

- data_load.py

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.readlines()
    return data

def load_data(data, var):
    dataset = list()
    for row in data:
        row = row.rstrip("\n")
        if var == 1:
            dataset.append(row.split(","))
        if var == 2:
            dataset.append(row.split(" "))
        if var == 3:
            dataset.append(row.split(";"))
    return dataset


def process_dat_data(data):
    dataset = list()
    for row in data:
        row_temp = list()
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            res = row[i].find(':')
            row_temp.append(row[i][res+1:])
        row_temp.append(row[0])
        dataset.append(row_temp)
    return dataset

def str2int(dataset):
    for i in range(0, len(dataset[0])):
        class_values = [row[i] for row in dataset]
        unique = set(class_values)
        lookup = dict()
        for j, value in enumerate(unique):
            lookup[value] = float(j)
        for row in dataset:
            row[i] = lookup[row[i]]

def str2float(dataset):
    for row in dataset:
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            row[i] = float(row[i])
    return dataset

def write_data(data):
    with open("tests_res.csv", 'a') as file:
        f = csv.writer(file, delimiter =',', lineterminator='\n')
        f.writerows(data)
```

- random_forest.py

```
from math import sqrt
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.base import clone
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

def cross_validation_split(dataset, folds_num):
    dataset_split = list()
    dataset_copy = list(dataset)
    fold_size = int(len(dataset) / folds_num)
    for i in range(folds_num):
        fold = list()
        while len(fold) < fold_size:
            index = randrange(len(dataset_copy))
            fold.append(dataset_copy.pop(index))
        dataset_split.append(fold)
    return dataset_split
 
def calc_accuracy(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0
 
def evaluate_algorithm(dataset, folds_num, trees_num, *args):
    attributes_num = int(sqrt(len(dataset[0])-1))
    folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, folds_num)
    scores = list()
    scores_sklearn = list()
    res = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=trees_num)
    for fold in folds:
        train_set = list(folds)
        train_set.remove(fold)
        train_set = sum(train_set, [])
        test_set = list()
        y_test_set = list()
        X, y = list(), list()
        for row in fold:
            #row_copy = list(row)
            #row_copy[-1] = None
            test_set.append(row[:-1])
            y_test_set.append(row[-1])
        predicted = random_forest(train_set, test_set, trees_num, attributes_num, *args)

        actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
        accuracy = calc_accuracy(actual, predicted)
        scores.append(accuracy)

        # Sklearn
        for row in train_set:
            X.append(row[:-1])
            y.append(row[-1])
        #res = clone(res)
        res.fit(X, y)
        accuracy_sklearn = res.score(test_set, y_test_set)*100
        scores_sklearn.append(accuracy_sklearn)
    return scores, scores_sklearn
 
def split_attribute(dataset, index, value):
    left, right = list(), list()
    for row in dataset:
        if row[index] < value:
            left.append(row)
        else:
            right.append(row)
    return left, right
 
def subset(dataset, ratio):
    sample = list()
    sample_num = round(len(dataset) * ratio)
    while len(sample) < sample_num:
        index = randrange(len(dataset))
        sample.append(dataset[index])
    return sample

def gini_index(groups, classes):
    examples_num = int(sum([len(group) for group in groups]))
    gini = 0.0
    for group in groups:
        size = int(len(group))
        if size == 0:
            continue
        P, E = 0.0, 1.0
        for single_class in classes:
            P = [row[-1] for row in group].count(single_class) / size
            E -= P ** 2
        gini += (size / examples_num) * E
    return gini
 
def roulette_split(dataset, attributes_num, threshold):
    classes = list(set(row[-1] for row in dataset))

    index_list, val_list, group_list, fit = [], [], [], []
    attributes = list()
    while len(attributes) < attributes_num:
        index = randrange(len(dataset[0])-1)
        if index not in attributes:
            attributes.append(index)
    counter = 0
    for index in attributes:
        for row in dataset:
            groups = split_attribute(dataset, index, row[index])
            gini = gini_index(groups, classes)
            index_list.append(index)
            val_list.append(row[index])
            group_list.append(groups)
            fit.append(1-gini)
            counter += 1
    wheel_size = 0
    fit_args_sorted = np.argsort(fit)
    for i in range (0, int(threshold*counter)):
        fit[fit_args_sorted[i]] = 0
    for i in range (0, counter):
        wheel_size += fit[i]
    
    selection_probs = [fit[i]/wheel_size for i in range (0, counter)]

    winner = int(npr.choice(np.arange(counter), 1, p=selection_probs))
    return {'val':val_list[winner], 'groups':group_list[winner], 'index':index_list[winner]}

def terminal(group):
    results = [row[-1] for row in group]
    return max(results, key=results.count)

def one_class(node):
    res = True
    for i in range(0, len(node)):
        if node[0][-1] != node[i][-1]:
                res = False
                return res
    return res

def are_the_same(node):
    res = True
    for i in range(0, len(node[0])-1):
        for j in range(0, len(node)):
            for k in range(0, len(node)):
                if node[j][i] != node[k][i]:
                    res = False
                    return res
    return res

def split(node, attributes_num, depth, threshold):
    left, right = node['groups']
    del(node['groups'])

    if not left or not right:
        node['left'] = node['right'] = terminal(left + right)
        return

    if one_class(left) or are_the_same(left):
        node['left'] = terminal(left)
    else:
        node['left'] = roulette_split(left, attributes_num, threshold)
        split(node['left'], attributes_num, depth+1, threshold)

    if one_class(right) or are_the_same(right):
        node['right'] = terminal(right)
    else:
        node['right'] = roulette_split(right, attributes_num, threshold)
        split(node['right'], attributes_num, depth+1, threshold)
 

def build_tree(train, attributes_num, threshold):
    root = roulette_split(train, attributes_num, threshold)
    split(root, attributes_num, 1, threshold)
    return root
 

def predict(node, row):
    if row[node['index']] < node['val']:
        if isinstance(node['left'], dict):
            return predict(node['left'], row)
        else:
            return node['left']
    else:
        if isinstance(node['right'], dict):
            return predict(node['right'], row)
        else:
            return node['right']
 

def bagging_predict(trees, row):
    predictions = [predict(tree, row) for tree in trees]
    return max(set(predictions), key=predictions.count)
 

def random_forest(train, test, attributes_num, trees_num, sample_size, threshold):
    trees = list()
    for i in range(trees_num):
        sample = subset(train, sample_size)
        tree = build_tree(sample, attributes_num, threshold)
        trees.append(tree)
    predictions = [bagging_predict(trees, row) for row in test]
    return(predictions)
```

- launch.py

````
from asyncore import write
from random_forest import *
from data_load import *

from random_forest import *
from data_load import *

def main():

    data_absence = read_file("datasets_v2/Absenteeism_at_work.csv")
    dataset_absence = load_data(data_absence, 3)
    dataset_absence = dataset_absence[1:]
    str2float(dataset_absence)

    data_car = read_file("datasets_v2/car.data")
    dataset_car = load_data(data_car, 1)
    str2int(dataset_car)
    
    data_opt = read_file("datasets_v2/batch_optdigits.tra")
    dataset_opt = load_data(data_opt, 1)
    str2float(dataset_opt)

    data_gas = read_file("datasets_v2/GasSensorDataset/batch1.dat")
    dataset_gas = load_data(data_gas, 2)
    dataset_gas = process_dat_data(dataset_gas)
    str2float(dataset_gas)
    
    sk_scores = []
    for_scores = []
    col_1 = []
    col_2 = []
    col_3 = []
    col_4 = []
    col_5 = []
    col_6 = []
    col_7 = []
    col_8 = []


    for dataset in [dataset_car, dataset_absence, dataset_gas]:
        sample_size = 0.05
        folds_num = 5
        for threshold in [0.2 , 0.5, 0.9]:
            print('Dla mojej informacji - threshold: ', threshold, '\n')
            for trees_num in range(1,10):
                sk_scores.clear()
                for_scores.clear()
                for i in [1,2,3,5]:
                    seed(i)
                    scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, folds_num, trees_num, sample_size, threshold)
                    score = sum(scores[0])/float(len(scores[0]))
                    for_scores.append(score)
                    sk_score = sum(scores[1])/float(len(scores[1]))
                    sk_scores.append(sk_score)
                if dataset == dataset_car:
                    col_1.append('SECOM Dataset')
                    col_1.append('SECOM Dataset')
                elif dataset == dataset_gas:
                    col_1.append('Gas Sensor Dataset')
                    col_1.append('Gas Sensor Dataset')
                else:
                    col_1.append('Absenteeism Dataset')
                    col_1.append('Absenteeism Dataset')
                for_mean = round(np.mean(for_scores),2)
                for_stdev = round(np.std(for_scores),2)
                for_best = round(np.amax(for_scores),2)
                for_worst = round(np.amax(for_scores),2)
                sk_mean = round(np.mean(sk_scores),2)
                sk_stdev = round(np.std(sk_scores),2)
                sk_best = round(np.amax(sk_scores),2)
                sk_worst = round(np.amax(sk_scores),2)
                col_2.append('Własna implementacja')
                col_2.append('Sklearn')
                col_3.append(trees_num)
                col_3.append(trees_num)
                col_4.append(threshold)
                col_4.append(threshold)
                col_5.append(for_mean)
                col_6.append(for_stdev)
                col_7.append(for_best)
                col_8.append(for_worst)
                col_5.append(sk_mean)
                col_6.append(sk_stdev)
                col_7.append(sk_best)
                col_8.append(sk_worst)
                print(trees_num)
    header = ['Zbiór danych', 'Implementacja', 'Ilość drzew', 'Próg selekcji', 'Średnia jakość', 'Odchylenie standardowe', 'Najlepsza jakość', 'Najgorsza jakość']
    file_data = np.column_stack((col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8))
    file_data = np.vstack((header, file_data))
    open('tests_res.csv', 'w').close()
    write_data(file_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```
````